# ArcMap Partial Refresh not working when Layout Graphics exist?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, layouts, graphics

I'm experiencing strange behaviour in ArcMap v10.3.
Adding layout graphic elements to all 4 corners of our map will result in a **full** refresh every time a point feature is moved.

Things that I've noticed are:

1. If I delete the graphic elements, ArcMap will perform a **partial** refresh using the extents of the feature being moved, which in my case is a point feature with a tiny extent so the refresh is super fast.
2. If we only have 2 graphic elements (1 in corner, 1 in center), ArcMap will create a bounding box between these graphic elements and refresh that area, regardless of where my point feature is (ie. a partial refresh will occur around my point feature as well as the bounding box between the graphic elements)

Has anyone else come across and/or fixed this issue?

Comment: Is your point element a graphic, or a feature in a layer which is being edited? If it's a feature, you should (probably) be editing in Data view, not Layout view.

Comment: It's a feature, we make edits in Layout view because the marker symbols change size in Data view depending on the view scale. And we're producing maps for hardcopy mapping, we make lots of edits in Layout view to arrange all elements for print (our maps are a combination on features and graphics)

Comment: Fair enough. It sounds like a bug/limitation when editing features in layout view with graphics present - possibly there's a reason why the programmers need to refresh the entire display. You could try ArcGIS Pro to see whether it has the same restriction?

Comment: Yea, thanks for the suggestion though. It used to work in ArcMap v9.3, not sure why the behaviour has changed in v10.3. We've coded our own tool to move Annotation using a Partial Refresh, it's just Points that are causing issues.